# Minimum Power Required

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, work, power

Here is a question, I found two methods to solve it, differing in the answers and I'm not sure why a method is incorrect.

**Question:** A fire hose of cross section area `A` is required to direct a jet of water to a height `h`, the minimum power of the pump needed for this hose is?

**Method 1:** 
$$ dp = \rho A dxV$$
$$ F = \rho A V^2$$
$$ P = F.V = \rho A V^3$$

**Method 2:** 
$$ m = \rho A dx$$
$$ KE = \frac{1}{2}mV^2 = \frac{1}{2}\rho A dx V^2$$
$$ P = \frac{1}{2}\rho A V^3$$

The correct answer stated is the one obtained from method 2.
Can anyone explain why the first method is wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method is wrong, because the velocity is not constant during the whole trajectory. This is what you implicitly assumed in the last step of the first method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the error. I will mark it as correct once it allows me too.